# Inverting a cellphone charger

Tags: voltage, inverter, charger

Hey guys id like to convert a charger brick to reverse the volts so invert it what. i mean is in my country its 220v so the charger brick must be able to take 5v and convert it into the said 220v now all .i need it for is a fun usb killer project i bought a fly zapper but its not enough volts so what componets would i need to turn or modify .
Ive tried to just put 5v into the usb port but nothing on the 220v side

Comment: -1 for careless writing, capitalisation and punctuation.

Comment: Limit yourself to devices of 3v maximum until you have a better understanding...

Comment: 1. There are no "fun" USB killer projects. 2. This topic is not compatible with the ethos of this site. 3. Fortunately the user's capabilities and the respondants' replies are liable to optimise outcomes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not match the site's intentions.

Comment: you fly zapper has plenty of volts for a usb killer (more than 220), just not enough current.

Answer (score 3):

Switched mode power supplies used in phone chargers are one-way, non-reversible devices.

[image]

*Figure 1. Not all processes are reversible. Pushing minced meat into the outlet of the mincer and turning the handle backwards will not produce a steak. Image source: [SousChef](https://www.souschef.co.uk/cast-iron-meat-mincer-no-10.html).*

See [How does a cell phone charger work?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/373851/how-does-a-cell-phone-charger-work/373880#373880) to understand why your scheme won't work.

---

Update:

> now all .i need it for is a fun usb killer (sic)

I didn't understand this bit at first but it seems from the comments that you wish to create a device to destroy USB ports. I hope nobody here will assist you in this childish stupidity.

Answer (score 2):

You would have as much luck doing this as inserting a 120V charger upside down into 230V.
[image]
Start by learning how things work before trying to be an inventor.

Shop, buy, open-up, test, break, fix, capiche?   That's how I learnt as a kid, by fixing things.  But at some time you must learn to read a lot.