# Circuit component controlling charging current

Tags: circuit-analysis, charger

I wonder how the circuit of a typical 5V phone charger looks like. In the figure given below, I sketched how I imagine it. Using this setup, could I control the current drawn by the phone by selecting different resistors, or would it catch fire?

[image]

Comment: this thing is not phone charger. i suggest you to research there is much to learn before you play with ac.

Comment: Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: Very close to duplicate of [How does a cell phone charger work?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/373851/how-does-a-cell-phone-charger-work) If you read that you will have a better understanding.